# OpenGEO templates and postGIS

Tags: postgis, boundless-suite

I am trying to display my shapefiles.shp with ol3edit template. On OpenGEO Suite I have successfully created an ol3edit application.I'm in possession of the ol3editApplication.war but the shapefiles.shp that I have loaded through the pgShapeLoader do not appear on the map, I can only see the default template map.

What I need help with, is to display the shapefile.shp I have loaded with pgShapeLoader on the template application I have created.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the config section of app.js and fill in the settings for the layer you have added in GeoServer: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/blob/master/sdk/src/main/resources/client/ol3edit/src/app/app.js#L10:L22